# How to Translate jQuery code into Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I typically use jQuery as a crutch to get stuff done, and move on to the next problem. However, with the introduction of Stimulus to Rails 6 I'd like to get better writing vanilla JS. I'm having difficulties re-writing the below `$.map` and `$.each` line:

```
handleSuccess(data) {
  const items = $.map(data, notification => { return notification.template })
  let unreadCount = 0
  $.each(data, (i, notification) => {
    if (notification.unread) {
      unreadCount += 1
    }
  });
  this.unreadCountTarget.innerHTML = unreadCount
  this.itemsTarget.innerHTML = items
}
```

My own attempts fall short of actually working.

```
items.forEach(data, (i, notification) => {
   if (notification.unread) {
     unreadCount += 1
   }
 });

 items.forEach(element, (i, notification) => {
   if (notification.unread) {
     unreadCount += 1
   }
 });
```

Comment: "My own attempts fall short of actually working." In what way don't they work? Is there an error (if so, what's the error message)? Do you get the wrong output (if so, what are the expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can convert `$.map()` to [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and convert the counter and the `$.each()` to an [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call. often `$.each()` is converted to `Array.forEach()`, but in this case you want to take an array, and convert it to a number, and this transformation is usually done by reducing.

Note: the problem in your own code is caused by the order of parameters - `$.each(index, item)` vs. `Array.forEach(item, index)`.

Example (not tested) - vanilla under commented jQuery

```
handleSuccess(data) {
  // const items = $.map(data, notification => { return notification.template })
  const items = data.map(notification => notification.template)

  // $.each(data, (i, notification) => { if (notification.unread) { unreadCount += 1 }});
  const unreadCount = data.reduce((count, notification, i) => notification.unread ? count + 1 : count, 0)

  this.unreadCountTarget.innerHTML = unreadCount
  this.itemsTarget.innerHTML = items
}
```

Comment: Thanks @OriDrori - `.map() `returns an array, which added an unexpected comma between each object. Extending your answer t to return a string containing the array elements concatenated together I added `.join('')` at the end of `data.map(notification => notification.template)`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has its own native map function (it didn't for a long time, thus the jQuery shim), and it's very similar to jQuery's. In fact, both Array.prototype.map() and Array.prototype.forEach() are very similar, with similar interfaces, just begin your invocation with the name of the array. So instead of jQuery `$.map(data, notification => { return notification.template })`, it's `data.map(notification => notification.template)` or similar. And the only difference between native map() and forEach() is that forEach() applies the function to each item in the array, while map() goes one step further and returns a new array of resulting values if invoked correctly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
handleSuccess(data){
const items = data.map(notification => notification.template)

let unreadCount = items.reduce(( total, curr) => curr.unread ? total +=1 : total)

this.unreadCountTarget.innerHTML = unreadCount
this.itemsTarget.innerHTML = items
}
```

The last two lines of your code are unchanged.